# Carry forward counter in Access

Tags: ms-access, counter

I have a Table whit a key ldData. 
I would like increment the counter. The next insert  must be 121500, not 120474.
How can I carry forward the counter?

ldData is the key of the table and I have a reference to ldData in others tables

[image]

Comment: So you need three records for each Id?

Comment: *"ldData is the key of the table"* - No, it isn't "*the* key". It cannot be the Primary Key on its own because it contains duplicates. Please [edit] your question to clarify your requirements. (At the same time, explain where the value 121500 comes from.)

Answer (score 0):

Besides setting your *ldData* data type to `AutoNumber`, you can also get the Max value and add 1 to it:

```
Dim id_ As Long
    id_ = Nz(DMax("ldData", "tblResult"), 0) + 1
```